# Genymotion error :Unable to create the virtual device server returned HTTP status code 403

Tags: android, emulation, genymotion

I'm trying to add a device on Genymotion Android Emulator, but after i select android device and press install i got some error, this error :

```
Unable to create the virtual device 
Server returned HTTP status code 403
```

how must i do to resolve this error?

Comment: are you able to resolve this error? if you able to resolve then provide possible solution.

Answer (score 1):

Possible solutions are:

1. Use another network ([Public VPN](https://www.google.com/search?q=public%20vpn)).
2. Download the .ova file from the browser to skip downloading step in Genymotion.
   **Must be signed in to Genymotion account at** https://www.genymotion.com/account/login/.

#### The following describes the second solution:

Right after the "Failed to deploy virtual device" screen with above mentioned error.

[image: Failed to deploy virtual device]

1. Open the log file: `%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Genymobile\genymotion.log`
2. Find near the end of file: `[Genymotion] [debug] Launching download`
3. Copy the URL that is on the next line `https://cloud.genymotion.com/vmtemplate/<vmtemplate_uuid>/getova`
4. Sign in at https://www.genymotion.com/account/login/ **Required for next step**
5. Open copied URL from **step 3** in the browser, this will return a JSON string
6. Copy .ova file URL from ova_url
   `http://dl.genymotion.com/dists/<aosp_version>/ova/<ova_name>`
7. Open copied URL from **step 6** in the browser and save the .ova file to `%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Genymobile\Genymotion\ova`. **Make sure the downloaded .ova file is located here**.
8. Retry adding the same virtual device in Genymotion. It should
   continue to "Retrieve and deploy the new virtual device".

Answer (score 0):

Check gennymotion settings, if you are logged in.

also check the sdk path in the adb tab

Answer (score 0):

first of go tho **settings** in genymotion and do the following steps.

1. login to the genymotion by giving user name and password in **account** tab.
2. go to **virtual box** tab and browse the virtual box installed path directory.
3. uncheck the use HTTP proxy if it was checked in **network** tab.
4. go to **ADB** tab and select the radio button of **use genymotion android tools(default).**.

Comment: try uninstall and reinstall it again.make sure you have installed virtual box

Answer (score 0):

I think genymotion stopped supporting free use. Now we have to purchase license.