# http error 403 when add genymotion device

Tags: genymotion, http-status-code-403

This my problem. Please help me with this.
I can't add device using genymotion. I don't know why.

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Genymotion error :Unable to create the virtual device server returned HTTP status code 403](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38909428/genymotion-error-unable-to-create-the-virtual-device-server-returned-http-statu)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You try other network and it ok